# ASP.NET Rendering XMl/XSLT direct from the web - problem with non virtual path

Tags: asp.net

i have a small problem. Im using the ASP.NET Xml control and want to pass it a url to a rss feed and a stylesheet - so that i can style the rss myself on my website. When applying the full web path to the xml control (http://www.myserver.com/myfeed.rss) i get an exception telling me that the document source is not a valid virtual path. What am i doing wrong? I would hate to download the file before showing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Instead of the DocumentSource property, there is a "Document" property (deprecated) which is an XmlDocument... i used this one instead.